# Apache2 404 error for index.html

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

I have an index.html file in `\var\www\html`

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        Servername <redacted>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log 
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

  <Location /alpha>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Restricted Access - Authenticate"
     AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd.users
     Require valid-user
   </Location>

   <Location /UserControl>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Access - Authenticate"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd.users
        Require valid-user
   </Location>

  Redirect /alpha /alpha/
  ProxyPass /alpha/ http://127.0.0.1:3838/alpha/
  ProxyPassReverse /alpha/ http://127.0.0.1:3838/alpha/


  WSGIDaemonProcess UserControl user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl/UserControl.wsgi

  <Directory /home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl>
            WSGIProcessGroup UserControl
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Order deny,allow
            #Allow from all
            Require all Granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

However, when I go to http://servername all I get is a 404 error. The page is not found. I've started at this for a while now and have no idea why.

For what it's worth, both http://myservername/alpha and http://myservername/UserControl both work so apache is correctly working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a /var/www/html/index.html file?

Comment: Yes, and I copied the most basic demo file I could find to make sure no errors. I even tried chmod 777 but also no fix. Likely not permission issue as it gives 404 not found and not 403-forbiddenZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted  # required in Apache 2.4
</Directory>
```

Is `index.html` actually specified as a `DirectoryIndex` somewhere?  Add it to your vhost config to be sure.

If neither of those help, play it safe and start simple.  Remove all the stuff that isn't relevant to the immediate problem, and use a very basic config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername <redacted>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"            # try quoting
    DirectoryIndex index.html               # just in case
    ErrorLog /full/path/to/error.log        # fully specified
    CustomLog /full/path/to/access.log      # fully specified
    <Directory "/var/www/html">             # quoted
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted                 # required in Apache 2.4
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I notice you have this:

```
Order deny,allow
#Allow from all
Require all Granted
```

Firstly, [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) recommend not to mix old and new format access control, so you probably want to get rid of `Order deny,allow`.  Secondly, I think `Granted` should be lower case, `granted`.

Answer (score 1):

After comparing your file with one of mine, and ignoring your authentication bits and proxying, it seems you are missing a  stanza relating to the document root...

Here's the relevant part from my working config - change the /var/www-example.com directory to whatever it is you want to use for your http://site/ root...

```
DocumentRoot /var/www-example.com
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www-example.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```